# How to cut walls along the pitches of the roof

Tags: modeling

I have a problem I have been tied up all the day with and I haven't solved yet.
I am trying to cut the walls of this house along the inclined pitches of this house.
Any ideas? I have tried almost all, add-ons, boolean operations etc. 
I think that the best way in this case would be to cut the vertical walls along the intersection between the roof and the walls themselves (pic. 1). Another option would be to extend the walls up underneath the pitches, but as you can see there are different heights and there are no snapping points to use and this is so annoying ;)[image: model of a house with inclined roof]
Please be quite clear because, in spite of my age, I am a newbee.
Thanks.

Comment: How about Snap to face?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there should be no difficulty using Knife Project.

- Select the roof, then the building
- Put the (active) building into Edit Mode.
- In an Orthographic view, looking straight down the roof ridge, hit 'Knife Project' in the Tool Region, Tools tab, Add section.
- In the Knife Project tool's own panel, check 'Cut through'.
- <kbd>V</kbd> Rip the newly created edges
- Hovering over the unwanted faces, <kbd>L</kbd> select all linked, and delete them.

[image]

Comment: If you have a roof that's irregular, with a different profile back and front, @moonboots' way would be a better option

Comment: oh yes of course, knife project, even simpler than a boolean   ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a copy of your roof, extrude the copy on the Z axis, give a *Boolean* modifier to your walls with *Operation* > *Difference* and the extruded roof as *Object.* It will create additional faces on the top but you can delete them.

[image]

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly. Actually I had tried that but it did not work. Don't ask me why. Anyway you made my day. Thanks "Moonboots". I think I will use this forum more often from now on.

Comment: You may have to correct your topology a bit with the Knife, though   ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no face at the top, no "ceiling". Hence, just lower the walls, along Z axis, and snap them to the "roof" (snap to face)

Answer (score 0):

The Shrinkwrap modifier is a flexible friend in such a situation. Its basic use is to dynamically snap elements of your mesh onto another target mesh object. This can also be limited to a **Vertex Group**, which is a collection of Vertices you define yourself.

To do that, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> after selecting the top row of vertices of your mesh, and confirm the menu that pops up:

[image]

You can find the new Vertex group in the Mesh Data tab in case you need to modify it later on (add or remove vertices):

[image]

Now add a *Shrinkwrap* Modifier to the walls mesh object:

[image]

Set the **Mode** to **Project**, and define target object (your roof mesh) and the Vertex group (collection of vertices that should change position). Also remember to set the projection axis (in my case Z):

[image]

Final result should look like this:

[image]