# How to trim wall to roofline

Tags: objects

[image]
How can I trim this wall to the roofline? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use the Knife Project tool

Comment: Check out the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123808/35559) .. ;)

Comment: Hi. For future screenshots, this may help: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 0):

Turn on snapping to face. (In blender 2.79.6 the shortcut is shift+Tab).

[image]

In edit mode, grab your vertices on the corner of the wall sticking through the roof and press "G" and "Z" to move it along only the Z axis. When the vertices snap onto the the correct face, let it go and there you go!

Hope that helps!